# How to simulate MySQL many connection errors

Tags: mysql, database

I recently had an issue with my production systems in which a MySQL server was blocking the application server, due to connection errors, and gave the following error:

```
Host 'xx.xx.xx.xx' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'
```

I'd like to find a way to simulate this condition (or even trigger the actual condition on a non-production server), so I can respond to it properly.  It's a pretty rare problem for my systems, but I'd still like to find a good way to respond to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simulate error connection you can connect to MySQL server and then end connection before succesfull authentication. For example by netcat:

```
nc -i0.1 <hostname> 3306
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce using this. MySql not considering this as a failed connection error

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid this problem by increase peer connections in mysql configurations

Logging to console/terminal with admin privileges

Flush all hosts using mysqladmin:

```
mysqladmin flush-hosts -u root -p
```

Open my.cnf (Linux) or my.ini (Windows) and change max_connect_error variable

```
max_connect_errors= 250000
```

Restart server with changes

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, it's a pretty rare problem.  It happened yesterday, and that was the first time I'd seen it in about 4-5 years.  It's not a problem I need to put much effort into avoiding, because it almost never happens.

And to clarify, I'm not asking how to _resolve_ the problem.  I'm asking how to simulate it so I can detect it and respond to it when it happens.

Comment: Martins answer is more appropriate here as the OP has asked how to simulate and reproduce the error.  However, using netcat or connecting to the socket on 3306 isn't reproducing the issue as well.